# google map first load gray and when resized it load the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Basically that's the problem I am loading the map on a article and it loads the google logo, the terms a condition text and the cursor change to the hand. The problem is that the images don't load but when I resize the page the images load normally, this is the script that I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function success(position) {
      var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
      mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
      mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
      mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';

      document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

      var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: coords,
          map: map,
          title:"You are here!"
      });
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
      error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }

});
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 info">

    ---some text---

    <button class="btn btn-warning continueCasual">Continue</button>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 formPub">
    --some inputs
    <article id="">

    </article>
</div>
```

the code that show the div where the map will be ist:

```
$('.continueCasual').on('click',function(event){
    $('.info')hide('fast', function(){  
            $('.formPub').show('fast');
    });
})
```

if the map its loaded outside the hidden element the map load perfectly, when the map its loaded inside the hidden element and then showed the map load gray

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

### Note

The map its hidden after the user make some action, I tested in a new document and it displayed the map, when I hide it and then show it the problem happened.

Comment: Far fetched but, px width instead of % may help.

Comment: the problem remains even if i use px.

Comment: The only problem I have with your code is the geolocation code doesn't run.  How are you hiding and showing it?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: So the map is hidden on page load? That does cause map loading issues. Does the map get hidden again? What's the exact interaction and visibility of the map?

Comment: the map ist hidden on page load, then its visible and it not hidden again

Comment: How do you show it?  Are you triggering the map `resize` event after it is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create the div with jquery you must have this div already defined before initialize the map

```
<div id = 'mapcontainer' style ="height: 400px; width: 500px;" ></div>
```

Leave only

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function success(position) {

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
            position.coords.longitude);
   .......
```

Comment: the problem persist, the problem happen when the map is not displayed and then displayed.